Toggle Serilog sink at runtime
I'm using code-based Serilog config (not appsettings). I want to toggle a sink at runtime; specifically Seq, but others too.
I know of the WriteTo.Conditional feature:
var isFooEnabled = true;
var isSeqEnabled = true;

services.AddSerilog((services, config) => config
  // ...
  .WriteTo.Console()
  .WriteTo.Conditional(x => isFooEnabled, x => x.Foo())
  .WriteTo.Conditional(x => isSeqEnabled, x => x.Seq(SEQ_URL))
);

But that code is located in the composition root (i.e. it's run during app start). I need to toggle a sink much later.
I'd probably need to resolve some service which can make the toggling decision. But how would I connect that to the above config code, at runtime? I couldn't find a hook for such functionality.
(Please note that switching to the appsettings approach is not feasible.)

I found a solution, based on this and this.
Add a type that encapsulates LoggingLevelSwitch:
public class SinkSwitch
{

  private readonly LoggingLevelSwitch _switch;
  private LogEventLevel _level;

  public SinkSwitch(LogEventLevel level)
  {
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(level)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(level));
    _level = level;
    _switch = new LoggingLevelSwitch(level);
  }

  public LoggingLevelSwitch Switch => _switch;

  public bool IsEnabled => _switch.MinimumLevel != LevelAlias.Off;

  public void Toggle()
  {
    _switch.MinimumLevel = _switch.MinimumLevel == LevelAlias.Off
      ? _level
      : LevelAlias.Off;
  }

  public void Change(LogEventLevel level)
  {
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(level)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(level));
    _level = level;
    _switch.MinimumLevel = level;
  }

}

During startup, before configuring Serilog, create the switch and store it as a singleton:
var sinkSwitch = new SinkSwitch(LogEventLevel.Information);
services.AddSingleton(sinkSwitch);

Then configure Serilog:
services.AddSerilog((services, config) => config
  // ...
  .WriteTo.Console(levelSwitch:sinkSwitch.Switch)
  .WriteTo.Seq(SEQ_URL, controlLevelSwitch:sinkSwitch.Switch)
);

Notes:

The trick is to use LevelAlias.Off
One would resolve the SinkSwitch from consumer code (e.g. a controller or some service) and invoke switch.Toggle()
One can use different switches for different sinks
This approach doesn't disable a sink, but rather sets the minimum log level high enough that log events are effectively ignored
When "disabled" the sink is nonetheless active, and processes all log events

